# Getting asynchronous values from ant-design vue form using onValuesChange

Tags: forms, vue.js, antd

I have a form that submits and send data to the backend using ant-design-vue. However, what I would like to achieve is give the user some form of feedback so while they type in the field they get to see the value {fullname placeholder} updated immediately, and clicking on the submit button sends it to the backend altogether.

```
{{ fullname || 'Your Name' }}

 <a-col :xs="{ span: 24 }" :lg="{ span: 12 }">
              <a-form-item label="Full Name">
                <a-input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Your Name"
                  :disabled="toggleEdit === 'edit'"
                  v-decorator="[
                    'fullname',
                    {
                      initialValue: this.fullname || '',
                      rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Name is required!' }],
                    },
                  ]"
                  autocomplete="name"
                /> </a-form-item
            ></a-col>
```

So the {{ fullname }} at the top updates immediately the user types Similar to v-model. But I would like to know how I can achieve this in ant-design-vue form with the onValuesChange method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `v-model` to bind your value on `input`firstly.
meanwhile, use `@click` on button with `submit` method

```
<a-input
  type="text"
  v-model="inputValue"  <---here
  placeholder="Your Name"
  :disabled="toggleEdit === 'edit'"
  v-decorator="['fullname',
  {
     initialValue: this.fullname || '',
     rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Name is required!' }],
   },
  ]"
  autocomplete="name"/>
<button @click="submit"></button>
...

data(){
  return{
     inputValue: ""
  }
}

methods:{
  submit(){
   // I send keyword with a object which include this inputValue by POST method
   // you can change it to yours, and keyword as well
   fetch("api-url").post({ keyword: this.inputValue }) 
   .then(response.json())
   .then(res => { //dosomthing when you get res from back-end })
}
}
```

Does above code is your requirement?

Comment: Actually, I could have easily plugged in v-model but I couldn't because I was using antdv library. It won't work with v-decorator, always throw an error.

However, I got it resolved by adding a @change listener then listening to the event and doing whatever I want with it.